# Access legacy C-dll with C# using unsafe fixed size array of struct within struct

Tags: c#, arrays, structure, fixed

I have a legacy C-dll to access a Hardware Device. The dll uses structures containing structure Arrays as function arguments. And I am having a hard time to get this working together with C# (in unsafe mode which is ok since access Speed is an issue here).

The original declaration from DeviceDll.h of the legacy C-dll Looks like:

```
    typedef struct tag_RESULT_JUDGEMENT
    {
        short nJudgementResult;             
    } struc_RESULT_JUDGEMENT;

    typedef struct tag_RESULT_FORMULA
    {
        float fFormulaResult[3];            
        float fAnalogResult;                
    } struc_RESULT_FORMULA;


    typedef struct tag_RESULT_SCRIPT
    {
        short nScriptNo;                    
        float fTime;                        
        short nFormulaCount;                
        struc_RESULT_FORMULA sFormula[32];
        short nJudgementCount;              
        struc_RESULT_JUDGEMENT sJudgement[8];
    } struc_RESULT_SCRIPT;

    WORD PASCAL GetResult(LPCTSTR pDeviceCode, struc_RESULT_SCRIPT_NO_LIST* pList, struc_RESULT_SCRIPT* pResult[]);
```

Declaring the C-dll functions in C# is done in the following way:

```
[DllImport("ExternalDevice.dll")]   
public unsafe static extern int GetResult(StringBuilder pDeviceCode, struc_RESULT_SCRIPT_NO_LIST* pList, struc_RESULT_SCRIPT **ppResult);
```

and the structure which I want to access I have declared in a way which unfortunatly gives an error:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public unsafe struct struc_RESULT_SCRIPT {
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public Int16 nScriptNo;

    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public float fTime;

    [FieldOffset(6)]
    public Int16 iFormulaCount;              

    [FieldOffset(8)
    public fixed struc_RESULT_FORMULA[32] oFormula;
}
```

Error:  Buffer of a fixed size must be of "bool", "Byte", . . . or "double"

Is there a way to declare a fixed structure Array within a structure so that I can use a structure-type variable afterwards as an Argument for calling the legacy DLL ?

What I have tried so far:

Avoiding a structure Array within a structure (rather clumsy but working)

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public unsafe struct struc_RESULT_SCRIPT {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public Int16 nScriptNo;

        [FieldOffset(2)]
        public float fTime;

        [FieldOffset(6)]
        public Int16 iFormulaCount;              

        [FieldOffset(8)
        public struc_RESULT_FORMULA oFormula01;

        [FieldOffset(8 + 16)
        public struc_RESULT_FORMULA oFormula02;

        . . . 

        [FieldOffset(8 + 31*16)
        public struc_RESULT_FORMULA oFormula32;
    }

    . . . 


    struc_RESULT_SCRIPT** ppResult;       //local variable => allocated on the stack => so it's already fixed

    . . .

    int iRv = GetResult(sbMpmIp, &oScriptList, ppResult);
    struc_RESULT_FORMULA oFormulaResult = ppResult[0]->oFormula01;
```

This is working - but accessing oFormula01 … oFormula32 for 32 structure-variables is rather clumsy. I would strongly prefer to get the result as an Array so that I can Access it like oFormula = arrayFormula[xx]; within a for - loop.

Is there a way to declare an unsafe, fixed structure Array within a structure in C# - or a feasable work-around ?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Not posting the struct declaration was a rather bad idea.  There is only one scenario where you *must* use a fixed buffer, this isn't it.  So don't, use ByValArray.

Comment: @HansPassant: I followed your advice using ByValArray together with LayoutKind.Sequential - like for example:
 [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 32)]
 public struct_RESULT_FORMULA[] sFormula;
and this seems to be working well.
Could you please explain the one scenarion where I have to use a fixed buffer ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation for fixed sized buffers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/fixed-size-buffers) there is no way use structs in them.

The best option seem to do as you have done and declare 1..n fields. The anwer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49764330/12342238) suggest the same thing. If the problem is simply not being able to loop over the fields, then consider adding a iterator block, like:

```
public IEnumerable<struc_RESULT_FORMULA> GetResultFormulas(){
    yield return oFormula01;
    ...
    yield return oFormula32;
}
```

An alternative would be a large switch statement/expression if you need random indexing.